# How one can find equations for eleven squares problem?

Tags: optimization

In the book *Which way did the bicycle go* was given that one can put eleven squares $S_1,\ldots S_{11}$ of side length 1 inside a square of side-length $3.877083$ if any pair of $S_i,S_j$ has no common interior points. It was said that this can be done by making two simultaneous equations and solve them numerically. But I don't see two different methods to make the equations. One is given in [Eleven unit squares inside a larger square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8698/eleven-unit-squares-inside-a-larger-square) . But how one can make the second one as it was unsolved in that link? I tried to follow the hint given in the link but I was unable to find the equation nor understand how Filmus got his first equation.

Comment: I didn't know this kind of problems. Very nice and challenging really.